# Migrating data from a Galaxy S3 Mini to a normal Galaxy S3?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-s-3, data-transfer, samsung-galaxy-s-3-mini

My sister has a Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini, but for whatever reason she threw her money away purchasing a regular Galaxy S3 yesterday, saying she prefer the bigger form factor. (I'm not gonna get into that.)

She asked me yesterday if there is any way to move her currently stored data in the S3 Mini to the regular S3 phone (both of which, I figure, are running the same 'Droid version). This basically encompasses contacts, messages, and app data (like notes and so on), but not necessarily the apps themselves.

I am a complete neophyte in Android stuff, since the only thing I've done in it is basically rooting an old Xperia X8 phone running 2.1 Éclair in order to have screenshot utilities work and to be able to delete the disgusting default home screen UI the phone has, and even most of that was done for me by someone else.

If this can't be done, I'll settle for being able to move the contacts from one phone to the other and screw everything else. ¬_¬